# "androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id" in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, junit, android-espresso

I tried several stack overflow questions to resolve this issue. I'm attaching the log for reference as follows:

`androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.gzw.presentation.fragment:id/count_view`

In my Testcase class, I had written like this :

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    activityRule.getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

}
```

In my another test method, I'm checking for UI element which is in fragment layout view.

```
 @Test
public void testInitializedViews() {

    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.count_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

}
```

Here **R.id.count_view** is textview resides within fragment layout. if anyone know how to use espresso for fragment layout views. Let me know here...

**Note: None of the google/stackoverflow link helped to resolve this issue..**

Comment: Could it be your `R.id.count_view` loads asynchronously? And begin a fragment transaction looks unnecessary in your `setUp()` method.

Comment: Nope, we are setting the count inside textview of fragment's oncreateView(), hence there is no async calls are made in that fragment class...